# How to add a Reset to Defaults button with Settings API?

Tags: options, settings-api

**How can I add a reset button when using the Settings API?**

I've have something like this that's storing my defaults:

```
$slider_options = get_option( 'nextslider_options' );

 /* Define the array of defaults */ 
$defaults = array(
    'width'             => 0,
    'height'            => 0,
    'effect'            => 'fade',
    'bullets'           => 0,
    'arrows'            => 0,
    'slidelength'       => 4000,
    'animationlength'   => 600
);

$slider_options = wp_parse_args( $slider_options, $defaults );
```

As a boilerplate I've used the [Settings Sandbox](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Settings-Sandbox).

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Checking for the key of the reset button and deleting the option?

Comment: Basically I want to add a 'Reset Options' button that will reset the options to their defaults, and I honestly have no idea how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new settings section for the reset button that is called on every tab. In the callback function for the field create the reset button. I would include the submit button here too to get both side by side.

In the validation function delete the whole option if the reset button is present in the request.